# Why would a Nikon lens be missing its rubberized focus ring?

Tags: lens, nikon, repair, equipment-damage

So, I was browsing eBay for Nikon 85mm f/1.8 lenses and I came across [this listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nikon-AF-Nikkor-85mm-f-1-8-D-Lens-FREE-US-SHIPPING-25841-/121188267933?pt=Camera_Lenses&hash=item1c3762379d&nma=true&si=YWOUvZxMEjs1sYesRBZDk5IEIP4%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557). The remarkable thing is the neat absence of the focusing ring, but otherwise pristine appearance of the lens. I was surprised when this was sold for a high price. I was even more surprised when I saw what I thought to be the same lens [re-listed today](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=121191307008). On closer inspection, I found that the seller was the same *and* the serial number was different.

So, my question is: what kind of repair work/accident would lead to this kind of neat removal of the rubberized ring, and in more than one lens? Is this part of some repair, where you have to remove the ring to detach the front element or something?

[image]

Comment: ebay images tend to vanish or be harder to access via original links once auctions close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to take a guess, they were using a custom focus ring, possibly for use with a follow focus on a DSLR video rig.  The ring itself is generally a pretty easily replaceable part, so it isn't too surprising that it still sold at a pretty high price as long as the lens is otherwise in good condition.

It's also possible they needed to get to screws underneath it for something and did a poor job removing it, thus didn't have the ability to place it back.

Comment: I think your guess is a good one, but I thought you could fit a follow focus jig on top of the ring?

Comment: @KaushikGhose - you can, but they are normally friction based.  You can swap it with a gear based one.